# How to display post count on tag page?

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress (ideally, with out the use of a plug-in) on a tag page I would like to show the number of posts that are tagged with the current tag.

Example:
There are 8 posts with the tag "baseball"
when you are on the tag page for baseball it says, "There are 8 posts about baseball"

It should dynamically know which tag page your on, get the count and print it. I have found several options for statically entering the tag name or ID and returning the count but my attempts to get them to work dynamically have been unsucessful.

This is what I was working with:

```
$taxonomy = "post_tag"; // can be category, post_tag, or custom taxonomy name


// Using Term Name
$term_name = single_cat_title;
$term = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy);


// Fetch the count
echo $term->count;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just print the `found_posts` property of the WP Query object

```
echo $wp_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: Perfect that is much quicker and more efficient than mine, which I finally got to work.

THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in your template named "tag.php" and enter the desired code in it.

Comment: Yes, I'm working in the tag.php page I'm just not able to get/find the desired code. The above doesn't work unless I enter a static tag name for $term_name.

Comment: Look at the WordPress codex function list, specifically those regarding get_post().

Comment: This seemed to do the trick: echo $wp_query->found_posts; 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution from [WP Recipes](http://www.wprecipes.com). They were kind enough to post this the day after I got an answer here. :)

```
<?php 
$feat_loop = new WP_Query( 'showposts=12&category_name=featured' );
echo "Query returned ".$feat_loop->post_count." posts.";
?>
```

It has different application but still very useful!

http://www.wprecipes.com/get-how-many-posts-are-returned-by-a-custom-loop?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Wprecipes+%28WpRecipes.com%3A+Daily+recipes+to+cook+with+WordPress%29